# Anylogic: Access Agents on a conveyor/in a Convey block?

Tags: java, agent, anylogic

I have 4 items that move into a 'convey' block from the materials handling library. I want to be able to access these items to change their variables. what function do I need?

I've tried `convey5.agents()` and `convey5.agentsInRange(1)` but not had much luck. I know I've managed to do something previously with queue blocks, is this possible with convey blocks?

many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `convey5.get(i)` where i is the index of the agent you are interested in. See Javadoc below:

[image]